# How to construct a serialized property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do something like the following, is there a way to do that?

new SerializedProperty(Vector3.zero);

Comment: No .. what would be the purpose of that? What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only (legal) way for developer to get SerializedProperty in its hands is to create source serializable object (class/struct with [System.Serializable] attribute or class derived from UnityEngine.Object) and feed it to the constructor of SerializedObject class. The result would contain full representation of given serializable object with all its child properties available. But no, as mentioned by @derHugo, it is not possible to construct only the SerializedProperty on its own, and frankly I don't even know why one would ever need it.